# ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do a simple app with Spring. I installed the plugin spring (Spring Tool Suite (STS)) for eclipse. I added Maven dependencies in the file pom.xml.im trying to add same Spring dependencies. 
i have problem with:
Spring-tx, 
Spring-orm, 
Spring-beans, 
and Spring-core

My problem is with :
spring-tx , spring-orm , spring-beans , spring-core when adding those dependencies, problems appear.

i tryed to add theme using the view Dependencies Add -> Select Dependency but i can not found Spring-tx and Spring-orm

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sid</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebotique</artifactId>
    <name>EBotiqueV3</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  

            <!-- Hibernate-->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL Connector-->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i'm getting followed errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:>3.2.2.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:pom:>3.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\MarwenBta\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\>3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-beans->3.2.2.RELEASE.pom.ahc985459e75c4648d7 (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:>3.2.2.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:pom:>3.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\MarwenBta\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\>3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-orm->3.2.2.RELEASE.pom.ahcf3ba8e697e9b4549 (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:>3.2.2.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-core:pom:>3.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\MarwenBta\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\>3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-core->3.2.2.RELEASE.pom.ahc23be8a1b03fa4ea4 (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:>3.2.2.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:pom:>3.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\MarwenBta\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\>3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-tx->3.2.2.RELEASE.pom.ahca3575630da624133 (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2 pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6 pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.0.Final  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.7    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.0.Final   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6   pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact asm:asm:jar:3.1    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.2    pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA  pom.xml /EBotiqueV3 line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

i have also problem applicationContext.xml

class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"

class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager"

class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"

class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"

the problem: Attribute : class
The fully qualified name of the bean's class, except if it serves only as a parent definition for child bean 
 definitions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
<bean id="datasource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eboutique"></property>
<property name="username" value="eboutique"></property>
<property name="password" value="user"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
<property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
<property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
<list>
<value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_EBOUTIQUE"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

Comment: You may try: Right click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project..

Comment: nothing happens the same problem

Comment: can you go to this folder: C:\Users\MarwenBta\.m2\ and delete everything forcefully then try: Right click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project.. and also select option "force update of snapshots/release"

Comment: i delete all the files inside repository?

Comment: Yes because there may be problem that some of your dependencies are not downloaded properly in that folder

Comment: hello, i need help

Comment: Can you check that after right click on project->Build path->Configure Build Path->Library section -> You have binded Jre from JDK properly?

Comment: Are you able to run command from command prompt: "mvn -version"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i solved my problem.

solution:

i used the Dependencies window or (right-click Maven -> Add Dependency) then i search for spring-core and spring-beans others I have not found.

and i add

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 18):

Adding repositories in Pom.xml will solve the issue.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Im converting my springboot app (used to use mysql to mariadb). Got the issue and this helped!

Comment: yes adding the repositories helped me in solving the issue.can you explain why this repositories to be added?

Answer (score 8):

Please try the steps in order as it might just be a glitch.

1. Project -> Clean
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Disable then re-enable dependency management (right-click Maven -> Disable Dependency Management then Maven -> Enable Dependency Management
4. Close and Reopen Project
5. Project -> Run as -> Maven Build -> Set goals as `clean install` -> Select options `Update Snapshots` `Debug Output` `Non Recursive` `Resolve Workspace Artifacts` -> Apply and Run
6. Repeat Step 5 after removing dependencies from ~/.m2/repository
7. Check that your Maven settings are configured correctly. If you are behind a proxy you'll need to configure the proxy settings in the global or user settings.

PS: Post debug output of maven build if it not solved.

Comment: one there is no Disable Dependency Management and two i don't know what did i did i just clicked Disable and Disable two object and then maven disappeared from the properties. So what should i do now?

Comment: how to post debug output of Maven build?

Comment: i need help pls

Comment: i uninstall and reinstall Maven and i have the same error

Comment: I do not have yet find a solution

Comment: My problem is with :
spring-orm and spring-tx when adding this two dependencys problems show up

Comment: My problem is with :
spring-tx , spring-orm , spring-beans , spring-core when adding those dependencies, problems appear.

Answer (score 0):

In Bean Configuration xml file add Following with appropriate Aop version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Go to Preferences -> click on "Maven" -> unclick "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories"** -> optional click on "automatically update maven projects configuration (experimental)"

***Thy "unclick" I mentioned above is extremely important if you want your dependencies to work properly!***